# View lowers itself when typing in TextInput React Native (Expo)

Tags: react-native, expo, textinput

In general the lay-out seems fine, the content is wrapped up inside a KeyboardAvoidingView as followed:

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView
                   keyboardVerticalOffset={-useHeaderHeight()}
                   behavior={"padding"}
                   style={styles.container}>
                   <View style={styles.conversationContainer}>
                       <ScrollView
                           ref={scrollViewRef}
                           onContentSizeChange={() => scrollViewRef.current.scrollToEnd({ animated: true })}
                           overScrollMode='never'
                           showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                           enableOnAndroid={true}
                           style={styles.conversation}>
                           {messagesView}
                       </ScrollView>
                       <View
                           style={styles.send}>
                           <TextInput
                               value={text}
                               textAlignVertical='center'
                               placeholder='Write your message'
                               style={styles.textInput}
                               blurOnSubmit={true}
                               onChangeText={(value) => setText(value)}
                           >
                           </TextInput>
                           <TouchableOpacity
                               style={[styles.button]}
                               activeOpacity={.6}
                               onPress={() => addMessage()}>
                               <IonIcon
                                   name={"arrow-forward-circle-outline"}
                                   size={30}
                                   color={'#00966E'}
                                   style={styles.icon} />
                           </TouchableOpacity>
                       </View>
                   </View>
               </KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

With the keyboard open, the TextInput is placed above the keyboard as intended.

[Keyboard Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGlM5.png)

But whenever I press a single keystroke, the entire view (including the TextInput), lowers down, covering half of the TextInput.

[Image of keyboard covering the TextInput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMlbp.png)

I have already tried changing the **KeyboardVerticalOffset** to different values as well as the changing the **behavior** to **"heigth"**, **"position"** or **none**. None of these happened to change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. This syntax helped me:  <KeyboardAvoidingView
behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}>